# Python unicode encryption algorithim

Tags: python, algorithm, math, encryption, unicode

I am building an encryption algorithm. It firstly takes the message you want to encrypt and an encryption key which can be **more than 8 digits.** It takes the message, using 'for' in Python it strips apart each char and puts them in a variable called 'char'. Now, it checks whether the ord(char) + encryption key is odd or even. If it's even then it subtracts the ord(char) by the key. If it's odd then it adds. it converts these digits to char by chr() and after every character being passed by this process, it displays the output to the user

Now, you might have noticed if let's say the result of ord(char) + key was odd, and the number was more than 1114111 (that's the number of usable unicode points), In that case it uses this algo-

```
            checkpoint = key - (1114111 - ord(char))
            if checkpoint < 1114111:
               mes += chr(checkpoint)
            else:
                mes += chr(checkpoint % 1114111)
```

and in if ord(char) + key was even and if key was more than ord(char), then it will use this-

```
            checkpoint = key - (1114111 - ord(char))
            if checkpoint < 1114111:
               mes += chr(checkpoint)
            else:
                mes += chr(checkpoint % 1114111)
```

The problem with my program is that when I use decryption, and the ord(char) + key is odd and more than 1114111, it simply gives me the wrong decryption. My tests indicate this and I can't figure how do I correct this problem. I will feel extremely grateful if you can correct my code or if you find out that there is a different twist to this problem or a new approach. I have posted the full code of both the programs (encryption and decryption)-

```
# encryption
code = str(input('Write your message, \t'))
key = int(input('Write your encryption key, use only numbers, \t'))
mes = ''
for char in code:
    if (ord(char) + key) % 2 != 0:
        if (ord(char) + key) <= 1114111:
            mes += chr(ord(char) + key)
        else:
            checkpoint = key - (1114111 - ord(char))
            if checkpoint < 1114111:
               mes += chr(checkpoint)
            else:
                mes += chr(checkpoint % 1114111)
    else:
        if ord(char) > key:
           mes += chr(ord(char) - key)
        else:
c
print(f'this is your encrypted messsage-   {mes}')
```

```
# decryption
code = str(input('Write your encrypted message, \t'))
key = int(input('Write your encryption key, \t'))
mes = ''
for char in code:
    if (ord(char) % 2) == (key % 2):
       if (ord(char) + key) % 2 != 0:
          if (ord(char) + key) <= 1114111:
             mes += chr(ord(char) + key)
          else:
            checkpoint = key - (1114111 - ord(char))
            if checkpoint < 1114111:
               mes += chr(checkpoint)
            else:
                mes += chr(checkpoint % 1114111)
       else:
           if ord(char) > key:
              mes += chr(ord(char) - key)
           else:
               checkpost = (key - ord(char))
               if checkpost < 1114111:
                  mes += chr(checkpost)
               else:
                   mes += chr(key % 1114111)
    else:
       if (ord(char) + key) % 2 == 0:
          if (ord(char) + key) <= 1114111:
             mes += chr(ord(char) + key)
          else:
              checkpoint = key - (1114111 - ord(char))
              if checkpoint < 1114111:
                 mes += chr(checkpoint)
              else:
                  mes += chr(checkpoint % 1114111)
       else:
           if ord(char) > key:
              mes += chr(ord(char) - key)
           else:
               checkpost = (key - ord(char))
               if checkpost < 1114111:
                  mes += chr(checkpost)
               else:
                   mes += chr(key % 1114111)
print(f'this is your decrypted messsage "{mes}"')
```

Comment: Don't be tempted to use this for any serious application. Professional algorithms undergo extensive testing for security. I can pretty much guarantee that any half-competent cryptanalyst will break yours without breaking a sweat. Take a look at [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I am just learning Python, and thought that an encryption algorithim is a good way to go

Comment: That's fine. Have fun with it and learn what you can. Just don't use it in a serious application.

Comment: Your "encryption" code must be wrong because it has a syntax error.

Comment: actually, 1114111 is not the number of useable codepoints. It will be less.

Comment: You can just use `mes += chr(checkpoint % 1114111)` in all situations, you don't need to differentiate the case where `checkpoint < 1114111`. In fact, the current logic with the `if...else` is likely giving the wrong result when `checkpoint` is negative.

Comment: @Andj I have tested 1114111, And it seems to be usable. Remember a chr does not necessarily need to exist.

Comment: @tueda rest assured that I am not getting a syntax error in vs code

Comment: there are 1114111 codepoints, the error is in the fact that not all those codepoints are useable, and should not be used. Its quite possible given the right inputs your code will throw encoding errors

Comment: @slothrop if you read the program and not only the excepts, checkpoint cannot be negative.

Comment: For instance, you really should avoid high and low surrogates,  some control characters, bidi formating characters, and noncharacters as a minimum.

Comment: @Andj I am saying that a chr does not need to exist, it simply needs to exist as a codepoint. If that is done then if ord() is ran over it then it will pinpoint to the correct codepoint over which decryption could be done

Comment: @Andj I will avoid the low ones:)

Comment: What's happening in the `mes += chr(key % 1114111)` statements? In the code paths that hit those statements, the decrypted character is independent of `char`, which doesn't seem right?

Comment: @Theassembler, what i am saying is you can convert any char to ord, manipulate it so that it is a decimal value equivalent to a codepoint in the range up to the max value. That's fine. Problem is then converting it back to a character to use in encrypted format, thats when the distinction between different types of Unicode characters comes in, and where you can potentially get UnicodeEncodeErrors

Comment: Depending on how you've set up your code to handle Unicode errros, you can lose encrypted characters

Comment: @Andj I will keep that in mind, although the sore in the thumb right now is that it gives me different chr rather than the intended ones they should be returning

Comment: To avoid the Unicode issues, encode the Unicode string to bytes via `.encode()` (default UTF-8) and encrypt the *bytes*.

Comment: @MarkTolonen there are no unicode errors in the code that have seen. .encode() only decrypts chr which are not assci, the rest remaining as it is

Comment: `.encode()` converts Unicode code points to bytes using the default UTF8 codec. Then encrypt the bytes of the result. That’s the way cryptography normally works.

Comment: Note: in general you do not encrypt characters, but bytes, and the more random are the bytes, the better it is, so often compression is done before applying encryption (to add entropy, and reduce brute force attacks): maybe all your pdf documents start with a very little changing header (and your text stars with your address).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that this way.

Just encode your data to bytes first, using a char encoding of your preference (utf-8 will cover all available **valid** characters).

Then create your encryption algorithm worried with the bytes, ranging from 0 to 256 (or group then in pairs, quadwords, 16byte groups with padding, whatever).

The unicode code space IS NOT LINEAR and is not LINEARLY USABLE as you want it to be. It is not because the highest theoretical codepoint is this number you repeat over and over again (as a side note: that is a terrible practice, that would cost you several points in any interview: when having a constant you need to refer to, keep it in a variable, so you can reach it by name)

Anyway, there are several value ranges that simply won't work when trying `ord(num)`, because they will lead to ilegal, reserved, or undefined characters, and even if you map then to characters with a  valid glyph representation, more than 90% of then will be unprintable in the majority of systems, as very few people have installed all the fonts needed to display everything - so if you would like a "copy-pasteable" encrypted string, the point would be missed anyway. And in all cases, when sending your "encrypted" (also pay attention to the comments that encryption is hard, and whatever you are doing there is just a toy), over the network, or store to a file, they will be serialized to bytes nonetheless.

TLDR;

1. start by *encoding* your text message to bytes: `real_message = message.encode("utf-8")
2. If you are to be minimally serious, compress those so as to increase entropy. Pyhton's ziplib does that:

```
In [28]: a = zlib.compress("Alô mundo!".encode("utf-8"))

In [29]: print(a)
b'x\x9cs\xcc9\xbcE!\xb74/%_\x11\x00\x1d#\x04\x89'

In [30]: print(zlib.decompress(a).decode("utf-8"))
Alô mundo!
```

(the bytestring is larger than the original in this case due to header structures needed by zlib - it will be smaller for a paragraph sized text)

3. Now, is your time to shine: be creative, and apply whatever you want to "disguise" those bytes. You can use the `bytearray` Python built-in to easily store modifiable bytes. You can use Python's `struct` package to group bytes in 4 or 8 unsigned (or signed) integers, or `array.array` to do the same.
4. when you are done, you still have a byte-string. If you want that to be printable, the correct thing to do is to map bytes to the printable range using one of the base64 or base85 (Python's stdlib base64 module contains encoders and decoders for both):

```
printable_message = base64.b85encode(bytes_encrypted_message).decode("ASCII")
```

5. be happy, and play around step 3.

Complete example using a simple "xor" encription (Python `^` operator), without compression:

```
from itertools import cycle

secret = "santaclausisfat".encode("utf-8")
message = "this is the very secret message"
raw_message = message.encode("utf-8")


encrypted_bytes = bytearray(byte ^ key_byte for byte, key_byte in zip(raw_message, cycle(secret)))

print(encrypted_bytes)

encrypted_text = base64.b64encode(encrypted_bytes).decode()
print(encrypted_text)
# YAY!!

original = bytes(byte ^ key_byte   for byte, key_byte in  zip(base64.b64decode(encrypted_text.encode()), cycle(secret))).decode("utf-8")
print(original)
```